# Android mediaplayer stop sound when another item is clicked

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, media-player, soundplayer

I'm building a list view soundboard and I need a code for play a sound when I click on a item and stop it when another is clicked, then start the new sound. I have tried many code but the app crashes.

Answer (score 1):

```
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;
```

Call playAudio() when an item clicked. it will stop the previous playing audio and play the new.

```
public void playAudio(int audioId)
{
    // stop the previous playing audio
    if(mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
    {
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, audioId);
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

call this method on item click

```
 playAudio(R.raw.sound); // change this sound depends on your item
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your media file in your **raw** folder
and then

```
 MediaPlayer song = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song1);
```

and when you click on an item in your listView

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
     super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
     song.release();
     song = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song2);
     song.start();
}
```

Comment: I know how to start the sound, but I need when I click on another item, previous stop and start the new.